# NoMethodError for new controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Cities#new** controller shows error involving *cities_path*, but I don't have it in any file nor in *CitiesController*. I checked all files, tried to restart the server but still nothing.

```
undefined method `cities_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9e4c1cb348>:0x00000003836140>
Did you mean?  city_path
```

**CitiesController**

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @cities = City.all
    end

    def show
        find_city
    end

    def new
        @city = City.new
    end

    def edit
        find_city
    end

    def update
        find_city

        if @city.save
            redirect_to city_path(@city)
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    def create
        @city = City.new(city_params)

        if @city.save
            redirect_to index_path
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    private

    def find_city
        @city = City.find(params[:id])
    end

    def city_params
        params.require(:city).permit(:name, :icon_url)
    end

end
```

**Routes**

```
  get "/cities/new" =>  "cities#new", as: "new_city"
  post "/index" => "cities#create"
  get "/cities/:id" => "cities#show", as: "city"
  get "/cities/:id/edit" => "cities#edit", as: "edit_city"
  patch "/city/:id" => "cities#update"
```

**Form** (error is raised on first line)

```
<%= form_for @city do |f| %>

    <% if @city.errors.any? %>
        <div class="errors">
            <ul>
                <% city.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label "Name:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= f.label "Icon:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :icon_url, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= f.submit "Pošalji" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm very unclear on why your create route is just `/index`, while everything else is scoped to `/cities`. Your cities index route should really be `/cities`, not `/index`.

Comment: It's index because after creation of the city, index page will be showed. All cities are showed on index page of the site, they don't have separate view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `form_for @city`, and `@city` is a new record, `form_for` will try to find a `cities_path` to POST the new attributes back to.

You should be using `resources :cities` in your routes file to automatically define the routes **and** their names. If you want to define a limited set of routes, you can use `:only` or `:except`:

```
resources :cities, only: %i(new create show edit update)
```

If you don't use `resources`, you either need to explicitly specify a path for your `form_for` call, *or* you need to provide a route named `cities_path` manually:

```
post "/index" => "cities#create", as: :cities
```

Note that index routes don't typically actually contain the word `index`, you should really just be posting to `/cities`, not `/index`.

```
 post "/cities" => "cities#create", as: :cities
```